# Primefaces dataTable with multiple row count

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

the next datatable is a report of files transferred and not transferred by each period (month / year). I need to include multiple row counts in the currentPageReportTemplate attribute. The total count, the count of transferred files and the count of not transferred files.

```
<p:dataTable id="repFiles" var="rep" value="#{reportFilesBean.list}" filteredValue="#{reportFilesBean.listFiltered}"
         paginator="true" rows="20" sortMode="multiple" emptyMessage="Empty result"
         paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport}  {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
         currentPageReportTemplate="Total: {totalRecords} / Transferred: #{reportFilesBean.countTrans} / Not transferred: #{reportFilesBean.countNotTrans}"
         rowsPerPageTemplate="10,20,30,40,50,100" scrollable="true"  style="width: 100%;"  >

    <f:event type="org.primefaces.event.data.PostFilterEvent" listener="#{reportFilesBean.postFilter}" />

    <f:facet name="header">
        Files transfered
    </f:facet>

    <p:column sortBy="#{rep.period}" filterBy="#{rep.period}" filterMatchMode="contains">  
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Period" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rep.period}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{rep.filename}" filterBy="#{rep.filename}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Filename" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rep.filename}" />
    </p:column>

    <p:column sortBy="#{rep.date}" filterBy="#{rep.date}" filterMatchMode="contains"> 
        <f:facet name="header">
            <h:outputText value="Date" />
        </f:facet>
        <h:outputText value="#{rep.date}" />
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
```

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class ReportFilesBean implements Serializable {

    private List<ReportFile> list;
    private List<ReportFile> listFiltered;

    private Long countTrans;
    private Long countNotTrans;

    public ReportFilesBean() {
        list = new ArrayList<ReportFile>();
        countTrans = 0L;
        countNotTrans = 0L;
    }

    public void generateReport(ActionEvent actionEvent) {
        Long[] c = {0L, 0L};
        list = dao.reportFile(c);
        countTrans = c[0];
        countNotTrans = c[1];
    }

    public void postFilter(ComponentSystemEvent e) {
        countTrans = 0L;
        countNotTrans = 0L;

        for (ReportFile r : listFiltered) {
            if (r.getFilename() != null){
                cantTrans++;
            } else {
                cantNoTrans++;
            }
        }
    }

    /* Getters and Setters */
}
```

At generate the report the variables countTrans and countNotTrans are displayed correctly. However at the time of filtering they maintain the value initially loaded. I debug the postFilter method and the count is successful but the datatable is not updated.

Please your help, I have read and I find no example with a similar scenario.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: where r u calling database ?

Comment: The query to the database is in list = dao.reportFile (c); I did not include this code to simplify the example. I use primeface 5.3.

Comment: Any suggestions are appreciated. Thank you.